# How can i use a splashscreen plugin in a phonegap app?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I am developing an android app using phonegap, but i had a challenge on showing a splashscreen, i have read many documentation(phonegap documentation) and many forum but i didn't find a solution for this. Which steps can i follow to solve this problem?
Plugin i tried is "**org.apache.cordova.splashscreen**"

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />    
<gap:splash src="splash.png" /> // splash.png will be your splash image
```

If you still have any problem, share your config.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is my config.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.myapplication.app" versionCode="10" version="1.0.0">

  <name>My App</name>
  <description>
   My App
  </description>
  <author href="https://myapp.co.uk/developer" email="jasperltd@gmail.com">
    Jasper Tech
  </author>
  <access origin=".*" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.2.7" />
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
  <gap:splash src="screen.png" />

  <content src="index.html" />
  <icon src="res/icon/icon.png" platform="android" width="124" height="124" density="mdpi" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="5" />
  <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
  <icon src="icon.png" />

  <application android:debuggable="false" />
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
  <feature name="App">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
  </feature>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the resources for each platform and the add the [platform](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens) section to your config.xml file:

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
```

The best way to do that is, I believe, using the Ionic CLI command but you have to install it before:

```
npm install -g ionic
```

With the CLI installed you can create a folder `resources` in the root (where your config.xml file is) and put your resources in there. 
If you want to build only the splashscreen just copy a `splash.png` file in there. More info [here](http://blog.ionic.io/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/).

When you have done that run:

```
ionic resources
```

and it will build the resources you need for each platform you have configured and it will configure the **config.xml** file for you.

The cordova splashscreen plugin has been moved here in the npm registry now so if you want to use the latest one:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Now you can add your splashscreen using

in your config file.

More info [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen).